# Select people working below a person

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join

I have a table called 'employee' in which people have an id and a number of his/her chef. Now I need to select the names of the persons with people working below them.

My table looks like this:

```
| id  | chef |
|-----|------|
|7.839|(NULL)|
|7.566| 7.839|
|7.698| 7.839|
|7.499| 7.698|
|7.521| 7.698|
|7.654| 7.698|
```

And my result should look like:

```
|id     | employees |
|-------|-----------|
|7.839  | 2 |
|7.698  | 3 |
```

I was thinking about something like this:

```
SELECT e.id, COUNT(e.chef) AS employees FROM employees e GROUP BY e.chef
```

But that selects the persons that work above them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

use `IS NOT NULL`

```
SELECT e.chef, COUNT(e.chef) AS employees 
FROM employees e where e.chef IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY e.chef
```

Comment: 1 error to point out, `GROUP BY` clause should be after `WHERE` clause.. else will cause error

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT chef as id, COUNT(chef) AS employees FROM employees 
WHERE chef IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY chef
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select count(id) as employee,Chef as ID from employee
where chef is not null group by chef
```